# Como eliminar valores Unicode de mi string

Tags: javascript, angular

Disculpen las molestias sobre mi pregunta, estoy trabajando con los Reactive Forms de Angular 14.

El problema es el siguiente:

Desde una API vienen nombres como el siguiente:

`console.log(res.value) // 'RODRIGUEZ PE&#209;A';`

y cuando hago un `form.control.setValue(res.value)` en el input se visualiza: `RODRIGUEZ PE&#209;A`

¿Hay algun metodo o algún tipo de logica que me normalice los string que vengan con este tipo de valores unicodes?

Cualquier tipo de sugerencia es de gran ayuda, desde ya **¡muchas gracias!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tú tienes ahí se llama [HTML entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity), y claro funciona cuando está dentro de un HTML, pero no dentro de un input.value

Con esta función que tomé desde [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4339083), puedes "decodear" el texto

```js
String.prototype.decodeHTML = function() {
    var map = {"gt":">" /* , … */};
    return this.replace(/&(#(?:x[0-9a-f]+|\d+)|[a-z]+);?/gi, function($0, $1) {
        if ($1[0] === "#") {
            return String.fromCharCode($1[1].toLowerCase() === "x" ? parseInt($1.substr(2), 16)  : parseInt($1.substr(1), 10));
        } else {
            return map.hasOwnProperty($1) ? map[$1] : $0;
        }
    });
};


var a = 'RODRIGUEZ PE&#209;A';

console.log(a.decodeHTML());
```

Comment: @MauricioContreras No sé si yo estaré haciendo algo mal, pero decodeURI no funciona. Dejé en mi respuesta un ejemplo al final para que vieras que no formatea el texto como se espera.

Comment: Genial, tuve que modificar un poco para poder ajustarlo a mi código, pero funcionó de maravilla, muchas gracias de verdad!!